# Does it matter what language is used when converting to WebAssembly?

Tags: webassembly

For example, C doesn't have the same solutions for security as Rust, but does  WebAssembly written in Rust have the advantages of Rust?

Would a program written in Rust and converted to WebAssembly be "safer" than  one written in C?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

While WASM prevents some attacks by itself, many attacks that Rust make impossible or harder to exploit would still be present in a C to WASM program. At least the following attack vectors exist in WASM:

- Integer overflows/underflows: Those are UB in C, but are defined in Rust.
- Buffer overflows: WASM uses a linear memory. Rust prevents buffer overflows, those are UB in C.
- Use after free: Impossible to have in safe Rust, those are common in C.

Some other attacks should not be possible using WASM whether using C or Rust as the source language:

- Arbitrary OS level code execution: WASM doesn't have those at all.
- Executable-space protection is not needed in WASM.

The only way to use those attack vectors would be to find a vulnerability in the browser itself.

Comment: "*to find a vulnerability in the browser itself*"... or in the JS layer that gives WASM access to the external world, and in the external world thus accessed.

Comment: @MatthieuM., "across the whole of the WebAssembly VM memory" -- not really. A Wasm module is sandboxed and can can only access memory objects it was explicitly given as imports. It can not modify other memories, especially not ones that are private to other modules. A "nanoprocess" is merely a tool convention for taking advantage of this already existing semantics.